# NET 6: How to use distributed cache managed by configuration?

Tags: asp.net-core, caching

I have a NET 6 web service.
My startup:

```
 bool dcachesqlserver = Configuration.GetSection("UseCache").GetValue<bool>(@"SqlServer");
            bool dcacheredis = Configuration.GetSection("UseCache").GetValue<bool>(@"Redis");
            bool dcacheInmemory = Configuration.GetSection("UseCache").GetValue<bool>(@"InMemory");

            if(dcachesqlserver)
            services.AddDistributedSqlServerCache(options =>
            {
                options.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("CacheDbConnection");
                options.SchemaName = "dbo";
                options.TableName = "CacheStore";
            });
            //
            if(dcacheInmemory)
            services.AddMemoryCache(options =>
            {
                // Overall 1024 size (no unit)
                options.SizeLimit = 1024;
            });

            if (dcacheredis)
            services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options =>
            {
                options.Configuration = Configuration.GetConnectionString("RedisConnection");//Configuration["RedisConStr"];
                options.InstanceName = "SampleInstance";
            });
```

My controller method is like :

```
public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger, IDistributedCache distributedCache, IMemoryCache memoryCache)
```

But if I do not set any caches in config file then it crashes because cannot inject distributedCache and/or memoryCache.

How can I (or end-user) configure what cache to use and probably no any cache to use?

Answer (score 0):

Need do not use MemoryCache but to use DistributedMemoryCache:
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
It was designed for development purposes and can be superseded any of Redis, SQL Server, PostgreSQL  real distributed caches

Answer (score 0):

> But if I do not set any caches in config file then it crashes because
> cannot inject distributedCache and/or memoryCache.

Well based on your shared code snippet and description, at the first glance, I would like to inform you that for [Distributed Memory Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-7.0#distributed-memory-cache)

we should use `builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();` instead of `services.AddMemoryCache` becasue, AddMemoryCache usually used for different purpose, so you need to updated that.

Apart from that, I think, your [Sql Server Cache Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-7.0#distributed-sql-server-cache) seems correct.

> How can I (or end-user) configure what cache to use and probably no
> any cache to use?

Well, depending on your needs its actually varies. Regarding usability [IDistributedCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-7.0#recommendations) is recommended by Microsoft. While implementing I DistributedCache you could consider following things:

1. You should consider your memory consupmtion,
2. What kind of Performance requirements do you have,
3. In Most scenarios Microsoft encourage to use redis cache in order to have performant solution.

Further more, keep in mind general data storage and retrieval can negatively impact the performance of sql server caches. So before implementation ponder over it.

**Note:** Please [refer to this official document for additional information you need.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-7.0)